# How to hide block with yii2 dropdown list

Tags: javascript, yii2

I have dropDownList in Yii2 project

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'license', ['options' =>['onchange'=>'getSalutationValue()'] )->dropDownList(['y' => 'Yes', 'n' => 'No']) ?>
```

i want hide some block if user seleckted value 'n'
I tried this function

```
function getSalutationValue() {
        var label = this.value;
        if(label == 'n' ) {
        document.getElementById('driver').style.display='none';
            }}
```

What am i doing wrong? Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing object of input field, so that you can use its value,
try this

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'license', ['options' =>['onchange'=>'getSalutationValue(this)'] )->dropDownList(['y' => 'Yes', 'n' => 'No']) ?>
```

in script

```
 function getSalutationValue(obj) {
    var label = obj.value;
    if(label == 'n' ) {
    document.getElementById('driver').style.display='none';
        }}
```

Updated:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'license')->dropDownList(['y' => 'Yes', 'n' => 'No'],['onchange'=>'getSalutationValue(this)']) ?>
```

Comment: It does not work, I think the dropdownList value is not passed

Comment: your syntax is wrong, even I forgot to see. check updated answer.